# How to configure an ubuntu server act as a VPN server and VPN client simultaneously?

Tags: vpn

I have two ubuntu servers, in two different locations
I have running Strong Swan VPN server on both of them, I need to connect server 1 to server 2, so when a client connects to server 1 all of its traffic must go through server 2.
What is the best solution?
Is there any way to make server 1 act as a strong swan VPN server and VPN client simultaneously?
or do I need another type of configuration?
I'm open to any kind of other ideas if you think that would make this process better performance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? The VPN you are using has its own support and that might be a much better place for this question. Ask them if this is even possible. https://www.strongswan.org/support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be perfectly possible using wireguard.  There are numerous guides on the internet explainig how to set up wireguard for both server and client use. I have set both up on my ubuntu system and they both work separately. I suspect it should work fine also simultaneously although there may be some routing and/or firewall issues so the traffic does not flow the wrong way.